# Loader can not be restarted after orientation changed

Tags: android

I'd like to use a demo to show this:

```
enter code here
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(buttonClickListener);
}

private OnClickListener buttonClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        startMyLoader();
    }

};

private void startMyLoader() {
    getLoaderManager().destroyLoader(0);
    getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, myLoaderListener);
}

/**
 * The listener for the group metadata loader.
 */
private final LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> myLoaderListener 
    = new LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>() {

    @Override
    public CursorLoader onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        return new CursorLoader(LoaderDemoActivity.this, 
        ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, 
        null, null, null, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
        cursor.moveToPosition(-1);
        if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text = "Load finished!";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    }
};
enter code here
```

After orientation changed, I clicked the button,
the onCreateLoader can be called,
but  onLoadFinished will not be called.

It seems strange.

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 14):

I faced the same problem. Please make a try call this.getSupportLoaderManager() in onCreate.
It solved my problem. Hope it will help you as well

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was very helpful! All I needed to do was call this method in my onCreate and my loaders started outside of onCreate started working with orientation change!

Comment: My cursorLoader was within a fragment.  I found that I had to call getLoaderManager() from within the onCreate method of the activity that owned the fragment.

Comment: Thanks! It has saved my day! The same for standard LoaderManager. It works much better if you call:
getLoaderManager() in onCreate() just to initialize it, even it you don't need it there.

Answer (score 5):

I think I have found the reason.

In Activity onCreate, it will load all the LoaderMangers(of its own or its sub-Fragments)
from NonConfigurationInstances.

```
    if (mLastNonConfigurationInstances != null) {
        mAllLoaderManagers = mLastNonConfigurationInstances.loaders;
    }
```

And in Activity onStart, it will try to start its own LoaderManger.

```
    if (!mLoadersStarted) {
        mLoadersStarted = true;
        if (mLoaderManager != null) {
            mLoaderManager.doStart();
        } else if (!mCheckedForLoaderManager) {
            mLoaderManager = getLoaderManager(-1, mLoadersStarted, false);
        }
        mCheckedForLoaderManager = true;
    }
```

But after config changed, mLoaderManager == null, so it will not start it.
And here is the problem!
If you try to start loader belong to this loaderManager, it will fail.

```
void installLoader(LoaderInfo info) {
    mLoaders.put(info.mId, info);
    if (mStarted) {
        // The activity will start all existing loaders in it's onStart(),
        // so only start them here if we're past that point of the activitiy's
        // life cycle
        info.start();
    }
}
```

note the mStarted value which will be set 'true' when LoaderManager started.

And there is two ways to solve this problem.

1. call getLoaderManger() in onCreate(), it will re-assign the mLoaderManager 
   and make it ready to be started in the subseuqent onStart().

   public LoaderManager getLoaderManager() {
       if (mLoaderManager != null) {
           return mLoaderManager;
       }
       mCheckedForLoaderManager = true;
       mLoaderManager = getLoaderManager(-1, mLoadersStarted, true);
       return mLoaderManager;
   }
2. have the loader located in fragments. Because in Fragments' onStart(),
   it will start its own LoaderManager.

   if (!mLoadersStarted) {
       mLoadersStarted = true;
       if (!mCheckedForLoaderManager) {
           mCheckedForLoaderManager = true;
           mLoaderManager = mActivity.getLoaderManager(mIndex, mLoadersStarted, false);
       }
       if (mLoaderManager != null) {
           mLoaderManager.doStart();
       }
   }

Comment: "But after config changed, mLoaderManager == null, so it will not start it" - if it were so you would get NullPOinterException when calling `getLoaderManager().destroyLoader(0);` - You are probably missing the point ;), use forceLoad and do not destroy-recreate loader every time as it is against how it was designed.

Comment: mLoaderManager will get assigned by "getLoaderManager(-1, mLoadersStarted, false" if it is null. So it will not throw NullPointerException. And I have to re-create the loader since something like URI in its creation should be changed.

Comment: This definitely seems like bug. Looking at the source in LoaderManagerImpl, its onRetain sets mStarted to false.  The only place mStarted is set back to true is in doStart().  If doStart() doesn't get called, no newly created loaders will ever be started (see LoaderManagerImpl.installLoader()).  The fact that simply calling Acticity.getLoaderManager() before Activity.onStart() is invoked, seems to indicate that this is just a state bug.  I solved my problem by adding a call to getLoaderManager() in my overridden Activity.onStart before calling super.onStart()

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to (neither ought to) destroy your `Loader` in order to reload it. `Loader` class is intended to be reusable.

Use `initLoader` instead. eg.:

```
getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, myLoaderListener);
```

If you want to force reloading allready registered loader:

```
getLoaderManager().getLoader(0).forceLoad();
```

If you are not sure if the `Loader` instance allready exists after configuration change event happened use `initLoader` instead of `getLoader` to retrieve your `Loader` instance on which you can call `forceLoad()`.

`getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, myLoaderListener).forceLoad();`

If you use support library then use `forceLoad` even after first instantation - there is probably a bug - I remind myself there are some questions about it on this forum - try searching older posts.

Comment: I don't think it is a right way to call forceLoad() manually if you have meant to use loaderManager to control all of that.

Comment: @user1335719 there's no such restriction, it only `Must be called from the process's main thread.`and loader must be started (check `isStarted()`)  which is obvious after retriving it with initLoader. `startLoading()` and `stopLoading` methdos are for inner use, not `forceLoad`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are not checking `savedStateInfo` while using fragments before you call your loader in activity `onCreate`

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // used to not overlap fragments
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        return null;
    }

    loadFragments();

    getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(LISTS_LOADER, null, this);
}
```

If you need to check for `savedInstanceState` fragments anyway you can check for any class variable that should be created after loader finished loading, as activity gets destroyed when rotating, but raising from previous state when rotating back.

Answer (score 0):

From the android's development site

> "They automatically reconnect to the last loader's cursor when being
>   recreated after a configuration change. Thus, they don't need to
>   re-query their data."

As far as I understand even when we start the loader explicitly the loader won't start. Since the destroy which we are calling should actually call `onLoaderReset()` once it is destroyed. But that method is not called once the orientation is changed, but is called before.

Still I may be wrong in this. This is my assumption. Further discussion would be appreciated.